# Are permutation groups used in statistics?

Tags: references, algebraic-statistics

I was told that there may be a connection between concepts in abstract algebra and applications in statistics (also confirmed by the 'algebraic statistics' tag on this website). I had no idea, so I'm curious. In particular, I wanted to understand how might permutation groups be used, as I believe they are a central and interesting concept in abstract algebra.

I'm trying to look into the theory online, but all I see are links to genuine research articles or other unhelpful things for me... I'm not a professional... If you can give me some examples, or perhaps easy to understand resources on such a topic, I would be glad.

I have an undergraduate understanding in statistics and algebra, so try not to use statistical word wizardry on this small tadpole of a mathematician.

Comment: Have you [searched our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=group+permutation)?  Other good search terms include "symmetr*" (for symmetries) and "invariant."  Group theory underpins modern methods of [tag:combinatorics].  Some more advanced abstract algebra methods (still at the undergraduate level), such as rings and ideals, have been exploited here to solve some problems: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6135/919 for instance.  Finally, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288198/919 I apply the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lecture on algebraic statistics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764389048) provides an excellent introduction into this topic. A more comprehensive overview is provided by Seth Sullivants book [Algebraic statistics](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-194/).

One key player of algebraic statistics are toric ideals $I_A$ motivated by a matrix $A$ coming from a log-linear model. Typically, one wants to find a finite generating set of $I_A$ (called a Markov basis) as they can be used for statistical tests (like Fisher's exact test, you may also want to have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207728/goodness-of-fit-test-on-sparse-contigency-tables-with-high-dimensionality/208157#208157)). Groups may appear in giving descriptions of the generating sets of those ideals, as typically, symmetry on the variables plays an essential role.

In section 4 of the [seminal paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/sturm98.pdf) by Persi Diaconis and Bernd Sturmfels, an example of such a generating set of the toric ideal (here, even an universal Gröbner basis) of the "no-three-factor interaction" model using $S_n\times S_n$.